# How do I see output for intermediate steps in a program?

Tags: programming

I understand Mathematica programs to be a series of steps enclosed in simple parentheses. Each 'step' ends in a semicolon except for the last. The program output is then the output of the last step and intermediate step output is suppressed. I wish to "see the program run", by seeing output for each step. Here is an example.

```
(
s=5;
f[x_]:=x^2;
g[x_]:=f[x]-5;
g[s] f[s]-s
)
```

Which evaluates to 495. I'd like to see f[x]=25 and g[x]=20 along the way. Thanks.

Comment: Lookup `Echo` in the documentation.

Comment: Extensive output you can get by: Trace

Comment: "I understand Mathematica programs to be a series of steps enclosed in simple parentheses." - not necessarily. Those are [compound expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html), but it does not need to be that way. If you care for a general intro, try [the Building Up Calculations Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html). It has a section about [stringing operations together](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#2645).

Comment: There is nothing worth seeing in the example you show except the value of the last line, which you will get. The output from 1st line is obviously 5; function definitions made with` SetDelayed` always return `Null`, which does print at top-level. Perhaps a better example is needed to make this question meaningful.

Comment: No answer would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your code like this;

[image: code]

#### Update

Note that my code eliminates the parentheses. With them revised code is:

[image: code]

Note the `Times` operators inserted by code editor, showing how the parentheses distort the interpretation of the code.

Comment: Thanks m_goldberg, but this doesn't work. This produces: SetDelayed::write: Tag Times in 25 g[x_] is Protected.

Comment: @John. You get that error because you still have code enclosed in parentheses, which you should not because they change the meaning of the code as clearly shown by the code editor.

Comment: Thanks m_goldberg. What I have submitted is my attempt to illustrate via a small example much longer & more complex code that includes an iterative process (not included here) that defines tolerance limits and loops back. In addition to getting the final result, My understanding is that the only way to run a program like this in Mathematica is to enclose the steps in parentheses. (Is that right?) I want to see some intermediate output and how this changes with each loop.

Comment: @John. In the light of your last comment, I would say that your question, as currently posed, is a very poor surrogate for your real problem. Since it's been closed, I recommend abandoning it for now. I also recommend you enter the phase "monitoring evaluation" in the search input field of the Documentation Center and take some time to study the first four hits. If those articles and the links they contain don't provide the info you need, then I suggest you post another question that better describes what you are really trying to do,

Comment: @John. also, enclosing a [`CompoundExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) in parentheses doen not make it a program. The notion of program in Mathematica is rather fuzzy and quite different from the concept you have formed from experience you may acquired from  programming languages like C or python.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @John. I also recommend that you peruse [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393) which discusses many (but not all) of the ways the Wolfram Language differs from more conventional programming languages. Doing so may help preserve your sanity. Most of them stem from Stephan Wolfram wanting Mathematica to be the world's foremost environment for performing mathematical computation. My belief is that the programming environment was included only as a support for that primary goal.